# Running "Animate" Using a Button

Tags: animation, button

I made the button below for launching an `Animate`, but it doesn't work at all! Why?

```
Button["Plot", Animate[Plot[k x, {x, 0, 3}], {k, -2, 2}]]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following to give the result that I think you are looking for.  I believe that Animate needs a window to run in.

```
Button["Plot", MessageDialog[Animate[Plot[k x, {x, 0, 3},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-8,8}}], {k, -2, 2}]], Method -> "Queued"]
```

The Method->"Queued" has been discuss in many other threads.

Answer (score 2):

```
Button["Plot",Animate[Plot[k x,{x,0,3},PlotRange->{{0,3},{-8,8}}],{k,-2,2}]//CreatePalette]
```

[Reference](http://wolfram.com/xid/0jbjc3xiizyxr1aq-cyuenm). Also, updated on `PlotRange` based on @JohnMcGee's answer.

[image: Mathematica graphics]